# How send redirect as post request. Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

i have my own  **AuthenticationSuccessHandler** and overriding method ***onAuthenticationSuccess***, where i need to redirect to some page with parameters from request before authenticate (i hope you understand what i mean, sorry for my english)

> getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);

How can i do this with POST method (by default it is GET method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it without `sendRedirect` method using [HTTP1.1 307 Temporary Redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#307) status code.

But AFAIK this is not a common practice and not all web browsers may support this.

Maybe server-side [forward](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) will suit your case.

Update:

If you want to send POST-redirect using spring-security API you may implement your own [RedirectStrategy](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/RedirectStrategy.java#L8).

[DefaultRedirectStrategy](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/DefaultRedirectStrategy.java#L31) uses `response.sendRedirect` that will result in `302` response code sending by servlet container (I'm not sure about every container, at least tomcat sends `302`).

Update 2:

You may send `307` back setting response status and "Location" header yourself:

```
resp.setStatus(SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
resp.setHeader("Location", absoluteRedirectUrl);
```

User-agent receiving this response must do next request using the same method that was used in previous request. So if first request was `POST` redirected request also will be `POST`.

Comment: Big thanks. I found this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#SC_FOUND, but i don't understand how to pack request in POST

Comment: What status tells that it is post?

Comment: @user1815058 please see update 2 (if I understand your questions right)

Comment: @Thanks for your answer, I suppose, it is the only solution, but it is very difficult for implementation